# React Redux JWT adding header

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I've been with this issue for days and I cant seem to figure out, Google also doesnt help.

I log in, I get JWT token from the API response, add the token to my localstorage and my plan is to then redirect to the dashboard. How would I go on about adding the token to header? I cant seem to figure out. When I push the dashboard route to history, the page doesnt get reloaded it simply renders the dashboard. The dashboard route is protected in my backend and it verifies if the token is valid from the header, if so then it lets on the route. but if I push to history then it completely ignores the backend. I tried doing like window.location.reload(), then it reloads but I cant figure out how to add the token to header from localstorage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a single page app, like a React app with React router, navigating between routes do not trigger a page reload or server request.

With your JWT on your client, you should then be able to access it and attach it to the ajax requests made by your React app.

Somewhere in your app, you would make requests using `fetch()` or similar, where you can configure the `Authorization: Bearer XXXXX` header.